# Re-encoding h.264 content with a different bit rate using Android MediaCodec

Tags: android, h.264

I'm attempting to re-encode a h.264 mp4 file with a different bit rate using the Android MediaCodec API's introduced in 4.2.

I am able decode and play the content (prior to changing the bit rate) using the MediaCodec API but if I attempt to re-encode the content with a different bit rate prior to decoding it I get garbled out put (a green screen with grey pixelation).

The code I am using is based on the Android Test Case android.media.cts.DecoderTest [Android Test Case android.media.cts.DecoderTest](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/43410/1/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecoderTest.java):

```
public void encodeDecodeVideoFile(AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor) {

    int bitRate = 500000;
    int frameRate = 30;
    int width = 480;
    int height = 368;
    String mimeType = "video/avc";

    MediaCodec encoder, decoder = null;
    ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers;
    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers;
    ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = null;
    ByteBuffer[] decoderOutputBuffers = null;

    // Find a code that supports the mime type
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs && codecInfo == null; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo info = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        if (!info.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] types = info.getSupportedTypes();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length && !found; j++) {
            if (types[j].equals(mimeType))
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found)
            continue;
        codecInfo = info;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + codecInfo.getName() + " supporting " + mimeType);

    // Find a color profile that the codec supports
    int colorFormat = 0;
    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
    for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length && colorFormat == 0; i++) {
        int format = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
        switch (format) {
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
        case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            colorFormat = format;
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Skipping unsupported color format " + format);
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Using color format " + colorFormat);

    // Determine width, height and slice sizes
    if (codecInfo.getName().equals("OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E")) {
        // This codec doesn't support a width not a multiple of 16,
        // so round down.
        width &= ~15;
    }
    int stride = width;
    int sliceHeight = height;
    if (codecInfo.getName().startsWith("OMX.Nvidia.")) {
        stride = (stride + 15) / 16 * 16;
        sliceHeight = (sliceHeight + 15) / 16 * 16;
    }

    // Used MediaExtractor to select the first track from the h.264 content
    MediaExtractor extractor  = new MediaExtractor();
    extractor.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
    MediaFormat extractedFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    String mime = extractedFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    Log.d(TAG, "Extartced Mime " + mime);
    extractor.selectTrack(0);

    // Create an encoder
    encoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
    MediaFormat inputFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, width, height);
    inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
    inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
    inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
    inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
    inputFormat.setInteger("stride", stride);
    inputFormat.setInteger("slice-height", sliceHeight);
    Log.d(TAG, "Configuring encoder with input format " + inputFormat);
    encoder.configure(inputFormat, null /* surface */, null /* crypto */, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    encoder.start();
    encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
    encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();

    // start encoding + decoding
    final long kTimeOutUs = 5000;
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    boolean sawInputEOS = false;
    boolean sawOutputEOS = false;
    MediaFormat oformat = null;
    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (!sawOutputEOS) {
        if (!sawInputEOS) {
            int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(kTimeOutUs);

            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {

                ByteBuffer dstBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0 /* offset */);

                long presentationTimeUs = 0;

                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawInputEOS = true;
                    sampleSize = 0;
                } else {
                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                }

                encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0 /* offset */, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs, sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);

                if (!sawInputEOS) {
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }
        }

        int res = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);

        if (res >= 0) {
            int outputBufIndex = res;
            ByteBuffer buf = encoderOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

            buf.position(info.offset);
            buf.limit(info.offset + info.size);

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {

                // create a decoder
                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType);
                MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, width, height);
                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
                format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", buf);
                decoder.configure(format, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);
                decoder.start();
                decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
            } else {
                int decIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                decoderInputBuffers[decIndex].clear();
                decoderInputBuffers[decIndex].put(buf);
                decoder.queueInputBuffer(decIndex, 0, info.size, info.presentationTimeUs, info.flags);
            }

            encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false /* render */);
        } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();

            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output buffers have changed.");
        } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat encformat = encoder.getOutputFormat();

            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format has changed to " + encformat);
        }

        if (decoder == null)
            res = MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER;
        else
            res = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);

        if (res >= 0) {
            int outputBufIndex = res;
            ByteBuffer buf = decoderOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

            buf.position(info.offset);
            buf.limit(info.offset + info.size);

            // The worlds simplest FPS implementation
            while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }

            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, true /* render */);

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                sawOutputEOS = true;
            }
        } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

            Log.d(TAG, "decoder output buffers have changed.");
        } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            oformat = decoder.getOutputFormat();

            Log.d(TAG, "decoder output format has changed to " + oformat);
        }

    }

    encoder.stop();
    encoder.release();
    decoder.stop();
    decoder.release();
}
```

The file I am trying to encode is from the Android cts Test Project:

R.raw.video_480x360_mp4_h264_1000kbps_30fps_aac_stereo_128kbps_44100hz

I'm guessing the problem is related to the format parameters I am specifying in the encoder MediaCodec but I can't figure out what is incorrect/missing.

Answer (score 2):

In your program, there is a design issue. In the loop `while (!sawOutputEOS) {` where you are trying to re-encode,

```
int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(kTimeOutUs);
```

Dequeues one buffer from the input / input port of the encoder

```
 ByteBuffer dstBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
```

Buffer pointer to the dequeued buffer

```
int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0 /* offset */);
```

The dequeued buffer is filled with the data from extractor. The output of an extractor is a compressed bitstream. This is **not a YUV** uncompressed frame.

```
encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex,....)
```

Here, the compressed bitstream is encoded. Since this is not a YUV frame, the encoder will try to perform a compression to the best of it's ability and hence, you observe a green illegible frame at the output of the encoder. I presume you are observing this on the screen due to the following portion of code where you decode the same content. This would have been observed even if the encoder's output was written into a file and played through a different player or on PC.

From the program, I presume your intended design is `Decode ==> Encode ==> Live Decode` for which your graph should be

```
MediaExtractor ==> MediaCodec (Decoder) ==> MediaCodec (Encoder) ==> MediaCodec (Decoder) ==> Display
```

P.S: Did you observe any memory violations when you run this program?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm going to experiment with decoding and then encoding the content and will report back.

Comment: The central portion of the CTS DecodeEditEncodeTest, added in Android 4.3 (API 18), may be of use.  Instead of decoding YUV data to ByteBuffer it moves the data through a Surface.  Info and link to code here: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest

Comment: @fadden I am yet to check `Android 4.3` sources. So thanks for the heads up!!